# Material ui datatable filter by selected rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, ecmascript-2016

I'm using muidataTable to display some data,and i have to calculate a value that requires filtering by selected row and reducing the array.
My code looks like:

```
Array.filter(//mylogic(e)=> e.selectedrow==true).reduc(...
```

What should i write inside the filter method to filter by selected row
Thank you.

Comment: Can anybody help please i could provide further clarifications

Comment: `.filter` should return a `boolean` value

Comment: what data does the function receive?